# Entity Framework Default value SYSDATETIMEOFFSET

Tags: entity-framework

When tracking entities and including columns like CreatedAt in table definitions in Entity Framework.

How to set the column default to the System Date Time Offset?

---

**EF add-migration code**  from this Entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Generates this C#:

```
    CreateTable(
    "dbo.Entity",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
            CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7)
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
```

Which generates this SQL:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entity] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CreatedAt] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Entity] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Generated Migration C# to this, and the SQL generated is correct.

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Entity",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
            CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7, defaultValueSql: "SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()")
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
```